# how to evaluate $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin x}}\text{d}x$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I was solving a physics problem and eventually the problem boiled down to solving the following integral:

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin x}}\text{d}x$$

I have already tried substitutions like $\sin x=t^2$ , $\sin x=t$ and have tried using the properties of definite integrals given on http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/integ/integ02/integ02.html but I could not solve this integral. Please help!

Comment: I doubt that it can be expressed in terms of elementary functions.  http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B%28Sin%5Bx%5D%29%5E%28-1%2F2%29%2C+%7Bx%2C+0%2C+pi%2F2%7D%5D+&x=9&y=9

Comment: use substitution t = tan(x/2)

Comment: @zimbra314,that substitution only complicates the integral. Did you get the answer using that substitution?

Comment: That's what I would try first. But, as of now, I'd like to believe sammy's comment

Comment: @SammyBlack, thanks... But do you have any idea about how to reach to that solution?

Comment: FWIW, Maple comes up with the answer $\sqrt {2}{\it EllipticK} \left( 1/2\,\sqrt {2} \right)$ for this one. The indefinite integral also has a (much more complicated) formula involving elliptic functions. No wonder you find this integral tricky.

Comment: Substituting y=sin(x) yields a solution in terms of the Gamma function.. No idea how to derive it though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the change $\sin(x)=\sqrt t$:

$$I=\displaystyle{1\over 2}\int_0^1 {t^{-{3\over 4}}\over\sqrt{1-t}}dt =
{1\over 2}\beta\left({1\over 4},{1\over 2}\right).$$

(change guessed after calculating the integral with Maxima)

Answer (score 6):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{{\cal I} \equiv \int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\dd x \over \root{\sin\pars{x}}}:\ {\large ?}}$

> With $x = \arcsin\pars{z^{2}}$ we'll get:
> $$
> {\cal I} = 2\int_{0}^{1}{\dd z \over \root{1 - z^{4}}}\,.\quad\mbox{With}\ z = t^{1/4}\,,\quad  
> {\cal I} = \half\int_{0}^{1}t^{-3/4}\pars{1 - t}^{-1/2}\,\dd t
> $$

Then
$$
{\cal I}=\half\,{\rm B}\pars{{1 \over 4},\half}=\half\,{\Gamma\pars{1/4}\Gamma\pars{1/2} \over \Gamma\pars{3/4}}
={\root{\pi} \over 2}\,\Gamma^{2}\pars{1/4}\,{\sin\pars{\pi/4} \over \pi} 
$$
$$\color{#00f}{\large%
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\dd x \over \root{\sin\pars{x}}}
=
{1 \over 4}\,\root{2 \over \pi}\,\Gamma^{\,2}\pars{1 \over 4}}
\approx 2.62206
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=\sin x$, then $t=u^2$, and recognize the expression of the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) in the new integral.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{d x}{\sqrt{\sin x}} & =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin ^{2\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)-1 }\theta \cos^{ 2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-1 }\theta d\theta\\
& =\frac{1}{2} B\left(\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2}\right) \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)} \\
& =\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \cdot \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right) \cdot \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right) \cdot \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)} \\
& =\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \cdot \frac{\Gamma^2\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}{\pi \csc \left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)} \\
& =\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2 \pi}} \Gamma^2\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
where the last step comes from the reflection property of Gamma function.

Answer (score -1):

So, which answer is prefereable?
$$
\sqrt{2}\;\mathrm{K}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right) = 
\frac{1}{2}\;\mathrm{B}\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}\right) =
\frac{\pi^{3/4}}{\sqrt{2}\,\Gamma(3/4)^2}
$$

Comment: any method of solving ??

Comment: These are the best known solutions.  Since $\Gamma(3/4)$ is thought to have no simpler expression, it would follow for your integral as well.